# How to get EC2 Cloudwatch data for ephemeral NVMe partitions (gp2/gp3)?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I know how to request CloudWatch data for instance root volumes (EBS).  But certain instance types (eg `i3.4xlarge`) also have `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and `/dev/nvme0n1p2` that do not show up in the AWS Console under the Storage tab.  I'd like to get metrics (eg IOPS) for those NVMe volumes.

Here is an example of a typical request:

```json
                        {
                          "MetricDataQueries": [
                            {
                              "Id": "readops",
                              "MetricStat": {
                                "Metric": {
                                  "Namespace": "AWS/EBS",
                                  "MetricName": "VolumeReadOps",
                                  "Dimensions": [
                                    {
                                      "Name": "VolumeId",
                                      "Value": "vol-XXXXXX"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                },
                                "Period": 60,
                                "Stat": "Sum"
                              },
                              "Label": "VolumeReadOps",
                              "ReturnData": true
                            },
                          ],
                          "StartTime": "2023-05-12T15:11:27Z",
                          "EndTime": "2023-05-12T15:26:27Z"
                        }
```

I am using this with:
`aws --region XXX cloudwatch get-metric-data --cli-input-json file://request.json`

I've tried Dimensions like `VolumeName: ephemeral0` but no dice.  (because [Terraform Docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#ebs-ephemeral-and-root-block-devices) suggest that *ephemeral* devices have name rather than id)

CloudWatch docs don't mention it either.  Is this possible?